# Azure ARM uniqueString function mimic

Tags: azure-rm-template, azure-resource-manager

I need to deploy Sql Databases into an Azure Sql Server using to ways: the ARM template way, and a more custom way using C# code. There's a ARM template function called `uniqueString(string)` that generate a pseudo random hash of a given string. It's a deterministic pure function.

I need to find a way to exactly mimic the behaviour of this function from my C# code. ie I need to reproduce this function into my C# code.

Where can i find the algorithm used by the ARM Api ?

[MSDN reference for uniqueString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-string#uniquestring)

Comment: I still would love some way of doing this that does not involve getting the Azure stack hub kit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some PowerShell code to do this here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/389thoughts/2017/12/23/get-uniquestring-generate-unique-id-for-azure-deployments/

I converted this code to C#:

```
public string GetUniqueString(string id, int length = 13)
{
    string result = "";
    var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(id);
    var hashArray = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed().ComputeHash(buffer);
    for(int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
    {
        var b = hashArray[i];
        var c = Convert.ToChar((b % 26) + (byte)'a');
        result = result + c;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't match the expected result of an ARM deployment template. try uniqueString('tyeth') as a single output parameter in an arm template and then test this function or any similar stack overflow suggestions. I get back 'zcztcwvu6iyg6' from Azure

Comment: For me neither this function nor the original posted Powershell does the trick...

Answer (score 8):

**Update 2023-01-05** - As suggested by other answers, there's an easier way now - just reference the `Azure.Deployments.Expression` nuget package which contains all of the Arm functions and then use the following convenience wrapper:

```cs
using Azure.Deployments.Expression.Expressions;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static class ArmFunctions
{
    public static string? UniqueString(params string[] values)
    {
        var parameters = values.Select(
            arg => new FunctionArgument(
                JToken.FromObject(arg)
            )
        ).ToArray();
        var result = ExpressionBuiltInFunctions.Functions
            .EvaluateFunction("uniqueString", parameters, null);
        return result.Value<string>();
    }
}

// "zcztcwvu6iyg6"
var unique = ArmFunctions.UniqueString("tyeth");
```

---

**Original answer** for posterity:

I've been researching this myself on and off for a *few years* now, and I've *finally* hit paydirt...

```cs
// "zcztcwvu6iyg6"
var unique = ArmUniqueString("tyeth");
```

My `ArmUniqueString` function is a wrapper around some dlls that are distributed with the [Azure Stack Hub Development Kit](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/overview/azure-stack/development-kit/) which is basically a virtual machine image that contains the Azure server-side platform that you can run locally...

```cs
private static string ArmUniqueString(string originalString)
{

    var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(
        typeof(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Templates.Engines.TemplateEngine)
    );

    var functions = assembly.GetType(
        "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Templates.Expressions.TemplateExpressionBuiltInFunctions"
    );

    var uniqueString = functions.GetMethod(
        "UniqueString",
        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic
    );

    var parameters = new object[] {
        "uniqueString",
        new JToken[] {
            (JToken)originalString
        }
    };

    var result = uniqueString.Invoke(null, parameters).ToString();

    return result;

}
```

You'll need to download the Azure Stack Hub Development Kit and unpack it to get the dlls:

- Download the [Azure Stack Hub Development Kit](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/overview/azure-stack/development-kit/) - warning: it's about 22Gb!
- Run the installer to unpack a 55Gb *.vhdx
- Mount the *.vhdx, or expand / unpack it locally
- Inside the *.vhdx, find this file  and unzip it somewhere:

  - `CloudBuilder\CloudDeployment\NuGetStore\Microsoft.AzureStack.Setup.Services.ResourceManager.5.20.1335.300.nupkg`
- The `content\Website\bin` folder inside the `*.nupkg` contains the necessary dlls

To use them, add an assembly reference to `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Templates.dll` (it has some dependencies on other files in the bin folder) and that contains the `TemplateExpressionBuiltInFunctions` class. The code above just uses reflection to invoke the private `UniqueString` function from that assembly, with a little bit of work to marshal the parameters into appropriate `JToken` types.

If you wanted to dig into the implementation details you could probably run a decompiler against the assembly to find out what it's doing under the covers...

Note - credits go to this blog article for pointing me in the right direction:

https://the.agilesql.club/2017/12/azure-arm-template-function-internals/

Comment: This is horrific and brilliant, thank you

Comment: Skip the signup: https://aka.ms/azurestackdevkitdownloader

Comment: Okay I did this. It concatenates a list of tokens with hyphen, utf8 encodes, does murmurhash64 on the bytes and returns the base32 string of it. I guess it later converts to lowercase and removes trailing equals signs, but I didn't check.

Comment: @GarethDavidson - note other answers have a better solution since I posted mine - simply add a reference to the Azure.Deployments.Expression nuget package :-).

Comment: I'm using it from Python, cross platform and can't redistribute Microsoft's DLLs. So it's probably cleaner and safer to rewrite it; it'll only be 5 lines of code

Comment: Added an implementation that doesn't have any dependencies. Another poster mentioned that the algorithm is just a base 32 encoding + Murmur and testing seems to back that up.

Answer (score 2):

This function is released in nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Deployments.Expression/
The implementation:
https://msazure.visualstudio.com/One/_git/AzureUX-Deployments?path=%2Fsrc%2FExpressions%2FExpressions%2FExpressionBuiltInFunctions.cs&version=GBmaster&_a=contents

Example:

```
using Azure.Deployments.Expression.Expressions;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var funcs = ExpressionBuiltInFunctions.Functions;
var jt = new JTokenExpression("test");
var output = funcs.EvaluateFunction("uniqueString", new JToken[] { jt.Value }).ToString();
```

Comment: I'm not sure you're supposed to be sharing the msazure.visualstudio.com link outside of Microsoft...

Answer (score 1):

Sam Cogan wrote a blog post on how to do this in C# here: https://samcogan.com/using-bicep-functions-in-c-if-you-really-want-to/

Inspired by Sam, I wrote a PowerShell module (for PowerShell 7) that does the same. You can install the module by running `Install-Module -Name AzExpression` which will give you command called New-AzUniqueString.

Here is an example on how to use it:
`New-AzUniqueString -InputStrings 'test', 'value'`
Which will output: **bhxq2thzm5dym**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a self-contained solution.

```
static class AzureExtensions
{
    private static string Base32Encode(this ulong value) {
        const string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz234567";

        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (var index = 0; (index < 13); ++index) {
            _ = stringBuilder.Append(value: alphabet[((int)(value >> 59))]);
            value <<= 5;
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
    private static ulong MurmurHash64(this byte[] data, uint seed = 0) {
        const uint magic0 = 2869860233U;
        const uint magic1 = 0597399067U;
        const uint magic2 = 2246822507U;
        const uint magic3 = 3266489909U;

        var hash0 = seed;
        var hash1 = seed;
        var index = 0;
        var length = data.Length;

        while ((index + 7) < length) {
            var temp0 = ((uint)(data[index] | (data[(index + 1)] << 8) | (data[(index + 2)] << 16) | (data[(index + 3)] << 24)));
            var temp1 = ((uint)(data[(index + 4)] | (data[(index + 5)] << 8) | (data[(index + 6)] << 16) | (data[(index + 7)] << 24)));
            var temp2 = (uint.RotateLeft(value: (temp0 * magic1), rotateAmount: 15) * magic0);
            var temp3 = (uint.RotateLeft(value: (temp1 * magic0), rotateAmount: 17) * magic1);

            hash0 = ((uint)((((int)(uint.RotateLeft(rotateAmount: 19, value: (hash0 ^ temp2)) + hash1)) * 5) + 1444728091));
            hash1 = ((uint)((((int)(uint.RotateLeft(rotateAmount: 13, value: (hash1 ^ temp3)) + hash0)) * 5) + 197830471));
            index += 8;
        }

        var remainder = (length - index);

        if (0 < remainder) {
            int temp0;

            if (4 > remainder) {
                temp0 = remainder switch {
                    2 => (data[index] | (data[(index + 1)] << 8)),
                    3 => (data[index] | (data[(index + 1)] << 8) | (data[(index + 2)] << 16)),
                    _ => data[index],
                };
            }
            else {
                temp0 = (data[index] | (data[(index + 1)] << 8) | (data[(index + 2)] << 16) | (data[(index + 3)] << 24));
            }

            hash0 ^= (uint.RotateLeft(value: (((uint)temp0) * magic1), rotateAmount: 15) * magic0);

            if (4 < remainder) {
                temp0 = remainder switch {
                    6 => (data[(index + 4)] | (data[(index + 5)] << 8)),
                    7 => (data[(index + 4)] | (data[(index + 5)] << 8) | (data[(index + 6)] << 16)),
                    _ => data[index + 4],
                };
                hash1 ^= (uint.RotateLeft(value: (((uint)temp0) * magic0), rotateAmount: 17) * magic1);
            }
        }

        var result0 = (hash1 ^ ((uint)length));
        var result1 = ((hash0 ^ ((uint)length)) + result0);
        var result2 = (result0 + result1);
        var result3 = ((result1 ^ (result1 >> 16)) * magic2);
        var result4 = ((result3 ^ (result3 >> 13)) * magic3);
        var result5 = ((result2 ^ (result2 >> 16)) * magic2);
        var result6 = ((result5 ^ (result5 >> 13)) * magic3);
        var result7 = (result6 ^ (result6 >> 16));
        var result8 = ((result4 ^ (result4 >> 16)) + result7);

        return ((((ulong)(result7 + result8)) << 32) | result8);
    }

    public static string UniqueString(this string value) =>
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s: value).MurmurHash64().Base32Encode();
    public static string UniqueString(this IEnumerable<string> values) =>
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s: string.Join(separator: '-', values: values)).MurmurHash64().Base32Encode();
}
```

Comment: Really nice answer. One tiny, tiny observation - the ARM / Bicep function takes a list of strings and concatenates them using a hyphen as a separator before encoding - might be good to add an overload that does that. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string#uniquestring for the function signature…

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround. I used a very simple ARM template which goal is to only output the result of the `uniqueString`command. Then I fetch this output in my C# code. This solution is not really the quickest one ;-), but it works as desired.

Comment: Care to share what that looks like?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a bicep template which will output a uniqueString for a resource group:

```
output unique string = uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)
```