# What is the source or spec of the uniquestring ARM function?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Does the ARM string function uniquestring have a spec or source code available so that we can get that predictable value in other areas, like PowerShell?

The use case is for determining names of new Azure resources ahead of an ARM deployment or maybe scenarios like a terraform deployment where we went to make the names compatible between the deployment toolchains. I do realize that we could have a very limited arm template that just returns the string as an output variable but that's a little I the wasteful side IMHO.

Comment: Just pulling some threads together - I posted an answer on a duplicate question - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67399362/3156906. It's not a full standalone implementation (it requires some reference binaries) but it *does* give the correct results...