# Reimplement the uniqueString() hash ARM function

Tags: azure, hash, cryptography, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment

The [uniqueString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string#uniquestring) function in ARM is a hash function that returns 13 chars. Executing the the function in the small script shown below `richard` for example becomes `b6oys6fwmheio`.

Does anyone know how this is implemented so one can reimplement it in code?

I'd be really handy to have when one creates and name things in the portal, and then just update it when deploying through ARM later.

ARM script for executing the function

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [],
  "outputs": {
    "uniqueName": {
      "value": "[uniqueString('richard')]",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Just using the standard hash algorithms and a very naive implementation doesn't really get you anywhere close either, as shown in this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lAGhDU). So it'd be really nice to get some details of the implementation.

- Sha1 gave `lujs8awci6eim`
- Sha256 gave `junhrxwwbjrth`
- Sha512 gave `slqvqdqjz3xcx`

Comment: I dont have bw to check, does this work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43295720/azure-arm-uniquestring-function-mimic

Comment: No ... I doesn't unfortunately ... It's just a way to implement something similar - but not an identical hash.

Comment: fffffff, i swear to god, there was an answer from @bmoore-msft with the exact hashing alg they are using, but I cant find it >..<

Comment:  @bmoore-msft 

Comment: Just pulling some threads together - I posted an answer on a duplicate question - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67399362/3156906. It's not a full standalone implementation (it requires some reference binaries) but it *does* give the correct results...

Answer (score 0):

A non-elegant solution (im not a PS dev :) ):

```bsh
param($text)

$tempPath = (New-TemporaryFile).FullName;
@'
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "text": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
        "uniqueName": {
            "value": "[uniqueString(parameters('text'))]",
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
'@ > $tempPath;

$result = New-AzDeployment -Location "westeurope" -TemplateFile $tempPath -TemplateParameterObject @{ text = $text };
return $result.Outputs.uniqueName.value;
```

Comment: Thanks. I was however hoping to be able to implement it in code and run locally, without having to create an Azure deployment and run it there.